# JQuery Enable (Changing 'disabled' to false) Not Working Based on the Input Text Value

Tags: html, jquery, dom

The following code is my jquery script:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#uid').val().length < 1) {
                $('#upw').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
                $('#upw').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        if ($('#upw').val().length <= 3) {
                $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
                $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the following is the problem part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="uid" value="" placeholder="Email or Phone Number" autofocus>
        <input type="password" id="upw" value="" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="submit">
</div>
```

The disabled attr gets disabled perfectly fine,
but when I type something in the text input field, the disabled attr would not change.
Please fix my code whenever needed.

Thank you so much for trying to help me out.
the disabled a

Comment: Code shown only runs when page loads. You need to use event listeners like `change()` or `on('input'` etc

Comment: this solved my problem, many thanks!